# Magento CRM Data sync

Tags: dynamics-crm-4, magento-1.4, crm

I have been working on a module to sync data between client side CRM tool(Microsoft C5 dynamics - MS sql DB) and magento.

I am seeing possibility to update the records from magento to CRM DB(event/observer from save_after methods) because when ever customers do some actions like edit/place order we can trigger a event and we can update the record into CRM DB. So it is single record update.

But how does it work for bulk records(I need to sync Products/Orders/Customers data between both way).

Yes,It should be via cron. But how can we pick only updated/added rows from both end to sync. Is that possible or only way is to compare each record on both DBs and update them in both side?

Please help me in this or can some one suggests me a right way to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are touching the areas of Master Data Management (MDM) which can be quite complex.

A direct answer to your question would be to do an SQL dump of the tables you need and import to magento. While not very elegant it will give you a batch update.

We use Windows Workflows and Biztalk for MDM processes between Magento and CRM.
We also use the security federation plattform to provide user information as claims to Mangeto, where one claim the the customer number.